# How does Hive partition works

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-partitioning

Lets assume the below table:

as schema: 
`ID,NAME,Country` and my `partition key is country`.

If my query is like:

`select * from table where id between 155555756 to 10000000000;`

The partition will not work in that case, right? .

On a simple note .What if I do not use partition key in my query . So table full scan will be there, right?

Comment: Both answers are yes... You could run an explain plan on the query with and without the partition filter

Comment: Think of a partition like a folder in the hdfs hierarchy leading to your storage files. Because that's basically what it is. `hdfs dfs -ls <LOCATION>` should show you that. And you can use `SHOW CREATE TABLE <TABLE>;` to determine the hdfs `<LOCATION>`

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to your first question is yes**, this query plan will not do partition pruning.

You can use the following statement to check if the query does partition pruning:
`explain dependency <your query>`

**Answer to your second question - It depends!**

If the `hive.mapred.mode` is set to **`strict`**, then hive will not allow to do full table scans, and few other *"risky"* operations like cross joins etc.,

Depending on the version of hive you are using, these settings also affect the number of partitions that can be scanned by a single query

- `hive.metastore.limit.partition.request` (or)
- `hive.limit.query.max.table.partition`